# Swift: Pagination in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift, parse-platform, pagination

I'm having trouble figuring out how Parse's (supposedly built in) pagination works. I have done hours of research, and almost everything I find is written in Objective-C, and when I try to convert it to Swift the app does not run.

I am running a PFQueryTableViewController to load videos in MPMoviePlayerControllers.

First, I'm unsure what to put in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Parse's AnyPic tutorial in Obj-C suggests to `return objects.count * 2 + (self.paginationEnabled ? 1 : 0)`. To be frank, I have no idea what that second part means, but either way, if I return *anything* in `numberOfRowsInSection`, such as `objects.count`, the app crashes immediately.

If I simply leave out `numberOfRowsInSection`, the first page of videos is completely successful. Once I scroll down all the way however, I get to the "Load More..." cell which was added by Parse automatically. Then the app freezes. The log simply reads `(lldb)` during this crash.

I suspect that there is not a cell loaded even though this other cell is appearing, but again I'm unsure what to do since whatever I put in `numberOfRowsInSection` crashes the app.

Next, I'm totally at a loss of what to put in `cellForNextPageAtIndexPath`. Parse's tutorial suggests:

```
PAPLoadMoreCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[PAPLoadMoreCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:LoadMoreCellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle =UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.hideSeparatorBottom = YES;
    cell.mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
return cell;
```

I am unable to mock this code in Swift, specifically the third line. I have tried running the app, skipping the if-statement, to no success. 
Perhaps this method needs to be complete in order for the pagination to work?

That is basically it as far as my questions, but here are some of the endeavors I've taken trying to solve this.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I tried the following:

```
if indexPath.row == objects.count - 1 { //Does NOT work if '-1' is omitted
                                        //Extremely glitchy
        println("Load next page")
        loadNextPage()

    }
```

This is moderately successful. It actually successfully loads more pages when the indexPath is close to the bottom. However, it is very glitchy. It crashes occasionally, saying `fatal error: Array index out of range (lldb)` This seems to be if I scroll fast enough to actually view the "Load More..." cell, so it seems like the same problem as above.

If somebody can help me with this, I will be (almost) forever thankful.

**Edit:** Code included for how I am working with data.

Here is my query for the table:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! { //Same code as when normally loaded videos

    var query = PFQuery(className:"post")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query

}
```

The important aspects of the "post" class are a videoFile and label. These are successfully loaded into PFTableViewCell.

Next, how I handle the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell! {

    super.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    println("Current indexPath: \(indexPath.row)")

    if indexPath.row == objects.count - 1 {
        println("Last current object")
        //loadNextPage()
    }

    //Parse: Assigning values(url, user, count) to cells
    let vidFile = object.valueForKey("videoFile") as PFFile
    let vidStr = vidFile.url
    let vidURL = NSURL(string: vidFile.url)
    myCell.videoURL = vidURL

    myCell.usernameLabel.text = object.valueForKey("user") as? String

    return myCell

}
```

This all works fine. Interestingly, `println("Current indexPath: \(indexPath.row)")` will not print ANYTHING when the "Load More" cell from Parse enters the view, which is making me suspicious.

I have some methods that make sure not to load a new video unless the cell is taking up a majority of the view. This would cause a crash if it tried to load a video in the "Load More" cell, but I have implemented checks to disallow this and it still crashes when the cell comes into view.

For example:

```
if indexPathToLoad.row != objects.count { 
        //Display video at proper indexPath
        cell.displayVideo()
    }

    else { // Does not fire
        println("Do not try to load new video: Load next page")
    }
```

Comment: Have you searched other Stackoverflow questions ?

Comment: See my example here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/XxLjxX29nuw

Comment: @ericgu Yes I have searched Stackoverflow. I checked out your example but it doesn't seem to address my question. I have adopted some things that I didn't have in my code but the app still crashes as soon as the "Load More" cell enters the screen.

Comment: Your statement: "If I simply leave out numberOfRowsInSection, the first page of videos is completely successful." is key. Leave it out.

Comment: Start there. Then you implement   textKey = "SomeObject", paginationEnabled = true, objectsPerPage = 25 in the init. Remove cellForRowAtIndexPath. Implement queryForTable. Everything should work.

Comment: Yeah, but the pagination still doesn't work. I think the basis of the problem is that there is NO indexPath.row for the "Load More" cell, which is why `if indexPath.row == objects.count - 1` works and `if indexPath.row == objects.count` does not fire.

Comment: It smells like you may have a data issue but I cannot really pinpoint without more code and screenshot of your backend

Comment: A worthwhile exercise is to to look at your backend to see if any blank rows exist

Comment: I'm skeptical to think so because if I loadNextPage() as soon as `indexPath.row == objects.count - 1`, so long as I don't scroll down fast enough to ever actually see the "Load More" cell, the next page successfully loads, and this will work for each page for all of the data in my Parse class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72934/discussion-between-george-poulos-and-ericgu).